# java method returning a modified string

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method that will accept 2 strings as arguments. The first string will be a phrase, the second also a prhase. What I want the method to do is to compare both strings for matching chars. If string 2 has a char that is found in string 1 then replace string 2's instance of the char with an underscore.

**Example:**

This is the input:

```
phrase1 = "String 1"
phrase2 = "Strone 2"
```

The output string is called `newPhrase` and it will have the string built from the underscores:

```
newPhrase = "___one 2"
```

Its not working for me I am doing something wrong.

```
public class DashedPhrase
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    dashedHelp("ABCDE","ABDC");
}

public static String dashedHelp(String phrase1, String phrase2) 
{
    String newPhrase = "_";

    for(int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++)
    {
        if(phrase.charAt(i) == phrase2.charAt(i))
        {
            newPhrase.charAt(i) += phrase2.charAt(i);
        }

    }

    System.out.print(newPhrase);
    return newPhrase;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working for me"? What is not working?

Comment: Also, your example makes no sense. Why is the `n` in the output?

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier for you to understand, you can use `StringBuilder` and its method `setCharAt()`.

Notice the `i < phrase1.length() && i < phrase2.length()` in the condition for the `for` loop. This is to make sure you don't get any `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("ABCDE");
    System.out.println("ABDC");
    dashedHelp("ABCDE","ABDC");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("String 1");
    System.out.println("Strone 2");
    String phrase1 = "String 1";
    String phrase2 = "Strone 2";
    dashedHelp(phrase1, phrase2);
}

public static String dashedHelp(String phrase1, String phrase2) 
{
    StringBuilder newPhrase = new StringBuilder(phrase1);
    for(int i = 0; i < phrase1.length() && i < phrase2.length(); i++)
    {
        if(phrase1.charAt(i) == phrase2.charAt(i))
        {
            newPhrase.setCharAt(i, '_');
        }
    }
    System.out.print(newPhrase);
    return newPhrase.toString();
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDE
ABDC
__CDE

String 1
Strone 2
___i_g_1
```

Comment: Why is the matching space character also replaced by an underscore?

Comment: @jlordo I'm sure you know why: the code does not make distinctions about chars. I just changed his code where he seemed to be really having trouble. To make it ignore space chars is simple, do you feel like I should add an exception for space chars?

Comment: My bad, my thoughts were twisted. There's an underscore at every matching character, therefore there is one where the space was. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`newPhrase.charAt(i)` doesn't let you replace a character, it just returns it. Java's Strings are immutable. I you want to change it you should use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Look into the `replace(int start, int end, String str)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to return a string that has the same length as `phrase2`, you need to iterate over each character of `phrase2`, and replace the matching characters of both phrases. And, of course, if `phrase2` is longer than `phrase1`, you need to include the remaining characters in the answer. You can try this:

```
public static String dashedHelp(String phrase1, String phrase2) {
    String ans = "";
    String subChar = "_";
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<phrase2.length(); i++) {
        if(i<phrase1.length() && phrase1.charAt(i) == phrase2.charAt(i))
            ans += subChar;
        else
            ans += phrase2.charAt(i);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Hope it helps

---

Of course, if you need to output `phrase1` with underscores in the places where `phrase2` has equal characters, you can interchange `phrase2` with `phrase1` in the above code.

---

**Testing it**

The complete class would look like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static String dashedHelp(String phrase1, String phrase2) {
        // The method code goes here
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dashedHelp("String 1", "Strone 2"));
    }
}
```

The output of this program is `___o_e_2`. This matches (approximately) your desired output.

Comment: @jlordo Thank you for your feedback, I think I've corrected the errors you catched.

Answer (score -2):

The code in the example won't even compile.

```
newPhrase.charAt(i) += phrase2.charAt(i);
```

That's a bad assignment. It's the same as writing

```
newPhrase.charAt(i) = newPhrase.charAt(i) + phrase2.charAt(i);
```

but the expression on the left side of the '=' isn't something to which you can properly assign a value.

Comment: I didn't downvoted this, but I think it is incomplete, because although it says what is wrong, doesn't say how to make it right.